# OpenXml Sdk, Styling in Tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, openxml-sdk

Is there any way to style table using openXml sdk? I am working on document creating in asp.net and stuck in styling tables. Is it possible to define style in template and when ever i structure my table through code, it will use this style?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest manually making a document with above table style and then using [OpenXMl productivity tools](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/06/02/4730.aspx) to examine how the word document is structured. You can then write code to construct the table.